# Difference between ancestor and ancestor-or-self

Tags: xslt, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I know about ancestor in xpath but what is this ancestor-or-self.
when  we have to use ancestor-or-self.Please give me any examples.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The axis name is quite self-explanatory I think. `ancestor` axis selects *only* ancestor(s) of current context element, while `ancestor-or-self` selects both ancestor(s) *and the current element itself*. Consider the following XML for example :

```
<root>
    <item key="a">
        <item key="b" target="true">
            <context key="c" target="true"/>
        </item>
    </item>
</root>
```

The following xpath which uses `ancestor` axis, will find the item `b` because it has `target` attribute equals `true` and `b` is ancestor of `context` element. But the XPath won't select `context` element itself, despite it has `target` equals `true` :

```
//context/ancestor::*[@target='true']
```

**output of the above XPath in [xpath tester](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) :**

```
Element='<item key="b" target="true">
  <context key="c" target="true" />
</item>'
```

contrasts with `ancestor-or-self` axis which will return the same, plus `context` element :

```
//context/ancestor-or-self::*[@target='true']
```

**output of the 2nd XPath :**

```
Element='<item key="b" target="true">
  <context key="c" target="true" />
</item>'
Element='<context key="c" target="true" />'
```

Answer (score 2):

Ancestor and Ancestor-or-self are the [XPath Axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp). An axis is a node-set relative to the current node.

The ancestor axis selects all the ancestors, i.e. parent, grandparent, etc of the current node whereas the ancestor-or-self selects all the ancestors, i.e. parent, grandparent, etc. of the current node and the current node itself.

Ancestor-or-self is generally used to locate the XML document tags or in [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=XSLT) that is a transformation language for XML designed to transform structured documents into other formats (such as XML, HTML, and plain text).

I believe that you may not need these axes to find the XPath in Selenium Webdriver as it deal with HTML tags not the XML tags and there are many other XPath axes that may help in finding the elements.