# How to match ancestor-or-self for contains Xpath?

Tags: xpath, contains, ancestor

I try to match ancestor-or-self of any element containing certain text string:

In step 1 matching of elements containing text works: `//*[contains(text(),"ABC")]`.

But I struggle with the syntax of adding an ancestor. I tried `//*ancestor-or-self::[contains(text(),"ABC")]` and `//*[contains(text(),"ABC")]/ancestor-or-self` without success.

What is the correct syntax for this?

The code and string I want match can look like:

```
<p><strong>Vertreten durch:</strong><br>Max Mustermann</p>
```

So I look for the string `Vertreten durch` to catch the parent element `<p>...</p>`

Comment: Can you add your XML (or a smaller version of it), with the output of the XPATH expression that your are searching for ?

Comment: Or take a look at: [Difference between ancestor and ancestor-or-self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963827/difference-between-ancestor-and-ancestor-or-self)

Comment: @Luuk: example added

Answer (score 2):

> The code and string I want match can look like:
>
> `<p><strong>Vertreten durch:</strong><br>Max Mustermann</p>`
> So I look for the string Vertreten durch to catch the parent element `<p>...</p>`

This XPath expression:

```
//*[not(text()[2]) and contains(text()[1], 'Vertreten durch')]//ancestor-or-self::p[1]
```

when evaluated selects the closest `<p>` - ancestor(-or-self) of the element (in this case `<strong>` whose only text-child-node contains the specified string: `"Vertreten durch"`.

---

**XSLT- based verification**:

Given this source XML document (the provided one, corrected to a well-formed XML document):

```
<p><strong>Vertreten durch:</strong><br />Max Mustermann</p>
```

**This transformation**:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    "//*[not(text()[2]) and contains(text()[1], 'Vertreten durch')]//ancestor-or-self::p[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**evaluates the XPath expression and outputs the node that is selected by it**:

```
<p>
   <strong>Vertreten durch:</strong>
   <br/>Max Mustermann</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an example xml, and named it `test.xml`:

```
<root>
   <line1>
       <line11>A</line11>
       <line12>B</line12>
   </line1>
   <line2>
       <line21>C</line21>
       <line22>D</line22>
   </line2>
</root>
```

Using [xmlstarlet](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), you can do:

```
D:\TEMP>xml sel -t -m "//*[contains(text(),'D')]/ancestor-or-self::*" -v "name()" -n test.xml
root
line2
line22

D:\TEMP>xml sel -t -m "//*[contains(text(),'A')]/ancestor-or-self::*" -v "name()" -n test.xml
root
line1
line11

D:\TEMP>xml sel -C -t -m "//*[contains(text(),'A')]/ancestor-or-self::*" -v "name()" -n test.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[contains(text(),'A')]/ancestor-or-self::*">
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="name()"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="value-of-template">
    <xsl:param name="select"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($select)[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

D:\TEMP>
```

EDIT: With a minimum example from HTML (I made sure it is also valid XML):

```
D:\TEMP>type test.html
<html>
<head>
   <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
   <p><strong>Vertreten durch:</strong><br />Max Mustermann</p>
</body>
</html>
D:\TEMP>xml sel -t -m //*[contains(text(),'Vertreten')] -c .. -n test.html
<p><strong>Vertreten durch:</strong><br/>Max Mustermann</p>

D:\TEMP>xml sel -C -t -m //*[contains(text(),'Vertreten')] -c .. -n test.html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[contains(text(),'Vertreten')]">
      <xsl:copy-of select=".."/>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you. But I need a XPath expression containing `ancestor-or-self` and '//*[contains(text(),"ABC")]'. In my environment I can only use a Xpath expression, as I asked in the opening post.

Comment: I read: "So I look for the string Vertreten durch to catch the parent element <p>...</p>", but you really **NEED**  `ancestor-or-self` and `//*[contains(text(),"ABC")]` ???  Did you notice that your example does not contain `'ABC'` ?

Comment: yes, it is just an example

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to process text nodes; use the string value of elements instead.

If the string value of an element E contains the substring `Vertreten durch:`, then the string value of all ancestors of E also contains this substring. So I think you simply need

```
//*[contains(., 'Vertreten durch:')]
```

If that doesn't answer the question, then the question needs to be clearer. An example would help.

Comment: I want to match some different use cases: 1. Something like: `<div><span>Vertreten durch:</span><span>Max Mustermann</span> </div>`, or `<div><p>Vertreten durch:</p>Max Mustermann </div>` or `<p>Vertreten durch:<span>Max Mustermann</span> </p>` or `<p><strong>Vertreten durch:</strong><br>Max Mustermann</p>` or the like. I search for names of managing directors on different sites - so I want to match the element or its parent with certain textual content. Your Xpath matches element with the given textual content - I need its parent or the whole element.

Comment: Then you could try `//*[.//text()='Vertreten durch:']`.